# PowerShell script to connect all network printers on servers and then remove them

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a list of around 15 servers that for each one of them I want to connect to all network printers on a printer server, and then remove all connections.
This is the powershell script I wrote-

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path <path to csv>

foreach ($server in $servers){

$printers = Import-Csv -Path <path to csv>
foreach ($printer in $printers){
$printername = "\\printerserver\" + $printer
Add-Printer -ConnectionName $printername | Out-Null
}


Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer | where{$_.Network -eq ‘true‘} | foreach{$_.delete()}

}
```

The servers CSV contains a single column with FQDN'S of said servers.
The printers CSV contains plain names of network printers.
This is the error I am receiving:

```
Add-Printer : The specified server does not exist, or the server or printer name is invalid.  Names may not contain ',' or '\' characters.
At line:9 char:1
+ Add-Printer -ConnectionName $printername | Out-Null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_Printer:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_Printer) [Add-Printer], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070709,Add-Printer
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Edit 1:

Content of servers csv:

```
servername
server01.domain
server02.domain
server03.domain
```

Content of printers csv:

```
printername
printer01
printer02
printer03
```

Comment: I don't really see the point of adding a printer just to remove it afterwards. What are you trying to achieve? (And did you read the Add-Printer docs and examples?)

Comment: can we see the input data? an example of the server and printer list? you've got several problems in this code.

Comment: @anothervictimofthemouse I edited the post and added an example of the lists, hope it helps. Thanks!